# GRPC Services issue

Tags: grpc

I am really new to the GRPC Client server architecture.
As far as I know it's introduced with .NET core 3.0.
Could you please let me know if we can develop grpc server with the .Net framework?
I am facing issue with the System.ServiceModel.dll if I try to connect from GRPC Service to the .Net freamwork library.

Answer (score 0):

in the [official documentation](https://grpc.io/docs/languages/csharp/quickstart/) it is referenced that indeed .NET supports gRPC.

Have a look at: https://grpc.io/docs/languages/csharp/dotnet/ and the tutorial https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/aspnet/core/tutorials/grpc/grpc-start?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio

gRPC can be quite confusing, I would always suggest to check out the tutorial to clarify missing bits of documentation!